# Excel sum function where some cells are string

Tags: string, excel, sum

I need to sum up some cells, but in some of these cells the data is a string (not applicable).  I want a formula that will ignore these cells but still sum up any others that contain numbers.  Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can use isnumber function

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the *SUM()* worksheet function:

[image]

The junk is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I would deal with errors in the cell...

As an alternative, and array formula could be used here...
Something like:

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR($A$1:$A$3);0;$A$1:$A$3)))
```

Paste it in a cell somewhere but make sure its an array formula...
Press F2, Press SHIFT+CTRL+Enter...